# What is vue router :matchRest(.*)* and when should I use it?

Tags: vue.js, path, vuetify.js, router

I ran into an issue, while debugging a route inside a component:

Inside my `Navbar.vue` component I have:

```
<v-list-group>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <v-list-item
            v-bind="props"
            title="All Projects">
        </v-list-item>
    </template>
    <v-list-item v-for="project in projects"
        :to="{name: 'project/folders', params: {projectId: project.id}}"
        :title="project.id">
    </v-list-item>
</v-list-group>
```

In my `router.js` i have a few different routes:

```
{
    name: 'project',
    path: "/project/folders/project/:projectId?/:matchRest(.*)*",
    component: () => import("./components/FoldersOverview1.vue"),
    props: true,
},
{
    name: 'project/folders',
    path: "/project/folders/project/:projectId?/:matchRest(.*)*",
    component: () => import("./components/FoldersOverview2.vue"),
    props: true,
}
```

When I navigate to */project/folders/project/1234*
I would expect Vuetify to expand the `v-list-group` and to highlight the `v-list-item`, as the named route in the `:to` property of the v-list-item is *project/folders*

BUT I experience that this is not what is happening...
The `v-list-item` list not beeing highlighted.

When I adapt my routes to:

```
{
    name: 'project',
    path: "/project/folders/project/:projectId?/:matchRest(.*)*",
    component: () => import("./components/FoldersOverview1.vue"),
    props: true,
},
{
    name: 'project/folders',
    path: "/project/folders/project/:projectId?/",
    component: () => import("./components/FoldersOverview2.vue"),
    props: true,
}
```

The `list-item-group` expands and the corresponding `v-list-item` is indeed **highlighted**.

My thoughs:
The first route named *project* does **match**,

but I suppose it **also matches** the second route *project/folders* 
- which is more strict than the first one, and everything works as expected in the same example. Is this correct?

Could somebody maybe explain, why the `v-list-item` with

```
:to="{name: 'project/folders', params: {projectId: project.id}}"
```

does only match the second route when `:matchRest(.*)*` is omitted? Shouldn`t both routes be matched anyway?